# how can I know which projection has this data?

Tags: coordinate-system

I have data in an unknown projection to me.

I open it in QGIS and I see that the shapes are ok, but I need to identify the projection in order to merge this data with other stuff.

The points look like WGS84 (EPSG:4326) but without comma.

If a point in WGS84 is like this: (-58,-34)

In this projection the coordinates are something like: (5670000,6120000)

Any ideas?

EDIT:
Here there are three pics, showing the situation.

This is the data I'm trying to import, that i don't know what is the projection. Look at the point marked, it corresponds to the central square.
[image: Data I'm trying to import]

This is my data (it is in lonlat even though it looks deformed). The coordinates shown are from the same central square.
[image: My data]

This is google maps showing also the central square coordinates.
[image: google maps]

SOLUTION image, transformed from Campo Inchauspe EPSG:22195 to lonlat. Thanks to mkennedy
[image: Solution]

Comment: Looks like either NAD83 or possibly some inappropriate UTM zone. What region of the world is this data in?

Comment: it should be around lon,lat: -58,-34 (that is La Plata, Buenos Aires, Argentina)

Comment: Are you working with projected data, or are you starting with the lat/long coordinates?  If the data are projected, you should be able to ID the projection by looking at the metadata.

Comment: I'm importing a .TAB file that has no projection information. I'm importing it as it would be WGS84, but I see those numbers (5670000,6120000). Around that area, there should be numbers close to (-58,-34)

Comment: @Jason It's definitely not UTM because the first coordinate is an order of magnitude greater than anything in UTM. "NAD83" makes no sense; it's a datum, not a projection. Because both coordinates are in the millions, we have to suspect this is some kind of a world projection. If "looks like WGS84" means looks like the Plate Carree projection, that suggests this is some form of cylindrical projection.  But it's not really possible to provide a definitive solution based on so little information. jperelli, at a minimum you need to post an image of your map, preferably with a graticule.

Comment: You are right. Sorry @whuber, I posted some pictures now.

Comment: The pictures help--to some extent. At this scale it is impossible to distinguish most projections. Presumably, the projection is a good one so that distortions in distance are on the order of parts per million and are undetectable. You would likely be successful choosing any cylindrical projection with a reference latitude close to yours and simply adjusting its false easting and false northing to position the features correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's in the Argentina zone 5. It's similar to a UTM zone, except the false easting is (zone number * million + 500000) and the latitude of origin is at -90 rather than the equator. The geographic coordinate reference system ("datum") is the issue as it could be on POSGAR 1994, POSGAR 1998, POSGAR 2007, or an older one like Campo Inchauspe. Here are the EPSG well-known IDs for various possibilities:

```
Campo Inchauspe  22195
POSGAR 1994   22185
POSGAR 1998   22175
POSGAR 2007   5347
```

Comment: EPSG:22195 fits perfectly. The other CRS show up in the neighbouring quartiers.

Comment: That's right, just as @AndreJoost says. Thank you very much. I couldn't try POSGAR 2007 though, because I couldn't find it in QGIS. I updated the question with the resulting pic.